# Throw exception and then propagate or return boolean and then throw exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have a service that gathers information and then, through a data loader service, data is uploaded to a DB. Now in the data loader, the input is validated before data loading takes place. From below two approaches, which one is preferable and should be taken as best practice?

- 1. Call the data loader and loader does the validation and sends a Boolean as TRUE if the input is found to be present in DB OR False if input is not found in DB. Then the caller takes this Boolean value and, if it is FALSE, it throws an exception complaining about reason of error in error message.
- 2. Call the data loader and loader does the validation and when the value, if not found, throws a custom exception providing details in error message. Caller eventually catches it, wraps it and re-throws it. Here "throw early catch late" principle can be followed.

Which is correct way? I would prefer 2 since it can avoid one condition checking here. Language I am using is Java 8

Comment: It is up to you how you design your APIs, but the 2nd one would be more or less standard.

Comment: Ok, maybe one more hint: using booleans as arguments or return values is generally poor practice where more than just a trivial check is involved. By using a boolean you loose the context, either the context of the argument value or in your case, the context, of the validation error. So exceptions for returns, enums for arguments, but not booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, there will be a Validator class which does the validation and throws an exception if the validation/condition fails. But I have seen patterns in which the Validator has something like isValid method which returns a boolean. If you want to fail fast use the first approach. But if there are multiple validations and you want to gather all the validation failures to give a detailed exception, use the second approach.

Comment: IMO poor advice

Comment: yeah it's something like isValid method and as of now only couple of validations so anything between 1 or 2 can be used I suppose , though my preference would be towards 2

Comment: +Oleg Sklyar, please let me know which part of the advice is poor? A method returning boolean is never a bad thing (Predicate). My advice was NOT to use boolean as arguments. isValid is useful if there are multiple validations need to done (a lot of validators which does specific validation) and if you want to give all the validation failures for a given input. If a validator throws exception, only the first validation failure will be propogated.